# Retrieving expired objects in Ehcache

Tags: java, configuration, caching, ehcache

I'd like to implement the following algorythm above Ehcache :

- try to get an element from the cache
- if the element is not expired

  - serve the value
- else

  - serve the expired value
  - refresh the element in the background

But I never get an expired element (Element.isExpired()). I tried to play with my cache configuration (especially TimeToLive and TimeToIdle) but I cant seem to get it to work as I want. I can list the keys in the cache, but if I "get()" an expired element, I always get a null.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just curious, did you ever come up with a solution or an alternate approach to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.  The documentation says that getting an expired element will remove it from the cache and return null.

I suspect the only time an element will come up as expired is if you have an event listener listenings for element expiry events but I can't say I've ever tested this.

Comment: Pay attention with the event listener (notifyElementExpiry). Only the key of the element is kown. According to following sentence in the API: As the Element has been expired, only what was the key of the element is known. Just had trouble with this.